# Get top row in multiple dimensions?

Tags: mysql, innodb, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table of jobs that has columns for unique id, app, env, the status of the job and the timestamp for it, along with other data not relevant to the question. Like so,

```
CREATE TABLE the_table (
    id       int           AUTO_INCREMENT,
    app      varchar(255),
    env      varchar(255),
    time_end datetime(3),
    status   varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Each job belongs to an app in en environment, env, and the values for these are limited, currently around ten for each of app and env. Some example data (with changed values):

```
INSERT INTO the_table(app,env,time_end,status)
VALUES
    ( 'app1', 'env1', '2017-11-14 14:45:07.037', 'finished' ),
    ( 'app1', 'env2', '2017-08-01 08:30:03.951', 'finished' ),
    ( 'app1', 'env1', '2017-10-05 21:36:22.716', 'finished' ),
    ( 'app2', 'env2', '2017-05-18 11:26:58.122', 'finished' ),
    ( 'app1', 'env1', '2017-09-26 00:35:37.914', 'finished' ),
    ( 'app1', 'env3', '2017-11-05 20:27:00.762', 'finished' ),
    ( 'app1', 'env3', '2017-06-04 16:55:19.089', 'finished' ),
    ( 'app3', 'env3', '2017-10-05 04:36:00.820', 'finished' ),
    ( 'app3', 'env3', '2017-09-22 04:11:51.602', 'finished' ),
    ( 'app2', 'env1', '2017-10-09 15:36:38.642', 'finished' ),
    ( 'app1', 'env2', '2017-10-04 16:07:48.272', 'finished' ),
    ( 'app1', 'env1', '2017-09-16 15:35:22.239', 'finished' ),
    ( 'app1', 'env1', '2017-10-12 19:53:29.434', 'finished' ),
    ( 'app1', 'env1', '2017-08-23 07:07:56.983', 'finished' );
```

I want to get, for each combination of app and env, and `status=finished`, the latest record. My first solution would be something like:

```
xs = Query("SELECT DISTINCT app FROM the_table")
ys = Query("SELECT DISTINCT env FROM the_table")


for app in apps do{
  for env in envs do{
    r = Query("SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE status='finished' AND the_table.env=env AND the_table.env=env ORDER BY time_end desc LIMIT 1")
  }
}
```

This could potentially be a lot of queries though and I would like to find another solution more idiomatic to SQL. This is using MySQL 5.7, so I can't use `limit` in subqueries.

Comment: no it is not clear.wht is your input table with some data and what is desired output ?

Comment: edited with more info

Comment: select app,env,max(time_end) time_end from table1 group by app,env

Comment: I tried that, but it seems it's not working since MySQL 5.7 with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: this is close to what I'm after but I can't get it to work exactly
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results

Comment: Is it safe to assume that `time_end` is unique per `(app, env)`? If not, is it at least unique for rows `where status='finished'`?

Comment: yes, that's safe to assume

Comment: Sounds like groupwise-max applied 3 times.

Comment: It's always better to provide to DDL rather than just grids. DDL and desired output, and we can help you easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted only the last `time_end` *value* per `(app, env)`, you could just use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
  app,
  env,
  MAX(time_end) AS last_time_end
FROM
  the_table
WHERE
  status = 'finished'
GROUP BY
  app,
  env
;
```

However, you want in each case the entire *row* where `time_end` is last. That is a classic "greatest N per group" problem. One way to solve it is in two steps: first get the last values themselves, then join them back to the original table and get the corresponding complete rows. The query above, therefore, is the first step. Use it as a derived table and join it back to `the_table` to get the final output:

```
SELECT
  t.*
FROM
  the_table AS t
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      app,
      env,
      MAX(time_end) AS last_time_end
    FROM
      the_table
    WHERE
      status = 'finished'
    GROUP BY
      app,
      env
  ) AS s ON t.app = s.app
        AND t.env = s.env
        AND t.time_end = s.last_time_end
;
```

Other database products support more advanced SQL syntax – specifically, window functions – that allows you to solve this category of problems without using a join, thus offering better performance. MySQL does not support window functions (yet?) but there is a way to work around that limitation using variables.

Specifically, you would use variables to *rank* rows within each `(app, env)` group based on the `time_end` value and then filter the rows on the ranking value:

```
SELECT
  derived.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      @rank := (app = @app AND env = @env) * @rank + 1 AS rank,
      ID,
      @app := app AS app,
      @env := env AS env,
      time_end
    FROM
      (SELECT @app := '', @env := '', @rank := 0) AS x,
      the_table
    WHERE
      status = 'finished'
    ORDER BY
      app ASC,
      env ASC,
      time_end DESC
  ) AS derived
WHERE
  derived.rank = 1
;
```

The query works like this:

1. The rows are sorted in such a way that identical `(app, env)` rows are arranged in groups, the last `time_end` row being the first row in each group.
2. Each row is then assigned a ranking value with the help of variables. Variables `@app` and `@env` hold the previous row's values of `app` and `env` and take part in calculating the `@rank` value: if the current row's `app` and `env` match the previous row's values, the `@rank` value is increased by 1, otherwise it is set to 1.

   Thus, the first row in each group always gets the value of 1, because the previous row belongs to a different group or, in the case of the very first group, is simply non-existent (`@app` and `@env` in that case each hold the initial value, an empty string).
3. The results are used as a derived table and are filtered on the ranking value: only the rows with the ranking value of 1 are returned (they hold the last `time_end` value in each group).

My only issue with this method is that it is very MySQL-specific, which, in my opinion, is worth keeping in mind. No other RDBMS supports this syntax (unless that product is a MySQL fork, like MariaDB, for instance).

Both methods shown can be found and played with in [this live demo at Rextester](http://rextester.com/PONFU3034).

Comment: Good answer, but I do think this could be totally done in one pass with MySQL variables.

Comment: Yes, I thought as much, so decided it wouldn't hurt to suggest that method as well.

Comment: What I mean is that you don't have to calculate rank. You just need to sort, and use the variables. You can make this even simpler.

Comment: Oh I see, you mean just flagging the first row, not calculating each row's ranking (your deleted answer helped to understand). Yes, I suppose that should work too. Less flexible because only applicable to scenarios where you want just one (topmost) row from each group, like in the OP's case, but makes sense nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, great solution. I assume this is that much faster than my solution below because it only joins the records that are already filtered by time, while mine has to trawl the while table?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so some googling gave me the almost full answer in this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results

Now it's not exactly what I'm after since the poster only wants to group by one column, and I want to group by two. The sql I ended up is the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM `the_table` o
  LEFT JOIN `the_table` b
      ON o.app = b.app AND o.env = b.env AND o.time_end < b.time_end
WHERE o.status='finished' AND b.time_end is NULL
ORDER BY o.time_end DESC;
```

My only concern is that this query is really really slow. My dataset is less than 3000 records, and this query is taking 1.5s. So my follow up question is, can I optimize this? All relevant columns, app, env and time_end have index.

---

**EDIT**: add index and explain info

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM deploy_infos;
+--------------+------------+-----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name                    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+-----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| deploy_infos |          0 | PRIMARY                     |            1 | id          | A         |        2241 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| deploy_infos |          1 | idx_deploy_infos_time_end   |            1 | time_end    | A         |        2241 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| deploy_infos |          1 | idx_deploy_infos_status     |            1 | status      | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| deploy_infos |          1 | idx_deploy_infos_app        |            1 | app         | A         |          14 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| deploy_infos |          1 | idx_deploy_infos_env        |            1 | env         | A         |           7 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| deploy_infos |          1 | idx_deploy_infos_time_start |            1 | time_start  | A         |        2241 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------+------------+-----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Explain:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE o.ID,o.app,o.env,o.time_end,o.user_id
    -> FROM `deploy_infos` o
    ->   LEFT JOIN `deploy_infos` b
    ->       ON o.app = b.app AND o.env = b.env AND o.time_end < b.time_end
    -> WHERE o.status='finished' AND b.time_end is NULL
    -> ORDER BY o.time_end DESC;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys                                                       | key                     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                                           |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | NULL       | ref  | idx_deploy_infos_status                                             | idx_deploy_infos_status | 768     | const | 1705 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using filesort           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | NULL       | ALL  | idx_deploy_infos_time_end,idx_deploy_infos_app,idx_deploy_infos_env | NULL                    | NULL    | NULL  | 2241 |    10.00 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1A) |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please provide index definition(s), and explain of query

Comment: @olovp  SHOW INDEX FROM the_table would be most helpful and the EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM ......., please.

Comment: Creating one index per column is not an optimal solution (in most cases). Some DBMS can make use of `INDEX ANDING`, but I don't think MySQL is one of them. However, regardless if that is supported or not, one appropriate index will outperform several one column indexes. For your case try:  `CREATE INDEX ... (app, env, status, time_end)` and see where that leads you.